# Modifying InstallShield MSM

Tags: module, merge, installshield

I've had the pleasure of not having to work with InstallShield very much, so I appreciate the answer to this is will be extremely simple, or more than likely, there is not much I can do about it (unless I compile my own MSM package?), but with the MSM Merge Modules, I have selected to use `Visual C++ 9.0 MFC (x86) WinSXS MSM`, version only states as 9.0, but getting a "SideBySide" error to say the version for `9.0.21022.8` is not found when the end user is trying to run the product.

With having 4 different flavours of version 9 in my `C:\Windows\winsxs` folder, I presume its not using the desired one of the version above, but there is no way to validate this in the properties of what is selected in InstallShield.

How can I either specify the selected MSM module is to use the set version of the files that is within the 9.0.21022.8 folder, or where can I find a MSM I can download to install over the top in InstallShield?

Thanks.

Comment: Would still love an answer to this question, but for the time being it is not as urgent as the individual testing did not have the other right prerequisites already installed.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose those 4 merge modules would be :

> ATL,
>   CRT,
>   MFC,
>   MFCLOC,
>   OpenMP.

May be the sxs error can be corrected if you install the x86 merge mods for a 32 bit installation
and install both x86 and x64 merge mods for a 64 bit installation.